# Using inverse Kinematics, how would I animate between movements?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, inverse-kinematics

So I was watching the example in the link below and have nearly recreated it. The only part I am struggling with is the lifting of the leg between movements! Any ideas on how I could recreate this? Im stuck between either using animations between movements or just coding in the leg lifting between points! Thankyou, any help would be appreciated.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e6Gjhr1IP6w&ab_channel=Codeer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using inverse kinematics, you can let the "foot" folow an imaginary path you code to move from the start position to the target position. The path can move directly from A to B, with some added height along it, based on the distance to the target.